# HTTP status for exponential authentication timeout

Tags: authentication, http-status-codes

On my web server, all API requests made related-to and before authentication are subject to an exponential timeout.

For example, after a user unsuccessfully logs in a few times, the delay before the server will accept a request will go from `2` to `4`, `8`, `16` seconds and so on.

Any requests made during these delay periods will be immediately rejected by the server with a `rety-after` header passed.

What HTTP status code should the server return in this case?

Comment: 429 Too Many Requests https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that one! Can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

*429 Too Many Requests*

http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429